# Улучшим перевод сайта вместе!

Tags: предложение, дефект

Не секрет, что в любом переводе могут встретиться ошибки. (Напомню, что наш сайт привязан к англоязычной платформе, и его русской локализацией занимается русскоязычное сообщество.)

Если у вас есть замечания к любым текстам на сайте (начиная с названий кнопок и кончая статьями Справки), пожалуйста, опишите их в своем ответе на это сообщение. Избавимся от ошибок на сайте, посвященном русскому языку!

Answer (score 1):

В английской версии unanswered и no answer имеют разный смысл, а на русский переводятся одинаково. Первое, насколько я понимаю,  означает, что нет ответа, принятого задавшим вопрос участником. Второе — полное отсутствие ответов.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв, мы работаем над более точным переводом.

Answer (score 1):

Просьба исправить [по этой ссылке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) опечатку в предложении:

> Для добавления разрыва **страницы** < br/ > в конце строки оставьте два
>   пробела

Выделенное слово "страницы" нужно заменить на слово "строки".

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв, исправим!

Answer (score 1):

В новом дизайне сайта в левой боковой панели меню опечатка в первом слове: "Главая" вместо "Главная".

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка исправлена.