# Настройки нового дизайна (информационное)

Tags: поддержка, faq

Хочу обратить внимание тех участников, которым не понравился свеженький дизайн нашего сайта, на то, что в этом дизайне существуют очень полезные настройки. Так, можно вообще скрыть левую боковую панель меню. И снять фиксацию верхней панели. Это может пригодиться тем, кто ценит полезную площадь экрана (особенно при увеличенном масштабе отображения страницы).

Чтобы внести изменения, нужно зайти в профиль пользователя (для этого можно кликнуть на своей иконке/аватаре — в верхней строке, где отражаются очки, медальки, обращения к вам и т.п.). Тогда вы увидите вверху слева меню:
**Профиль — Активность — Настройки**
Заходите в **Настройки** и находите там галочки в блоке "Навигация по сайту".

Если я написал слишком непонятно, оставьте комментарии — я тогда сделаю скриншоты.

**Дополнение 18.09.27.**
В случае обнаружения багов в новом дизайне (то есть ситуаций, в которых работа сайта явно не соответствует описанию и ожиданиям), просьба сообщать об ошибках по этой ссылке:
[Responsive design for international sites has been released](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315856/responsive-design-for-international-sites-has-been-released)

Если Вы не уверены, является ли ситуация ошибочной, можете оставить сообщение в этой теме (в качестве ответа), тогда мы сможем принять решение сообща.
По вопросам перевода дизайна на русский язык (ошибок, опечаток и т.п. в текстах дизайна) просьба сообщать в этой теме:
[Улучшим перевод сайта вместе!](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316/%D0%A3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5)

Comment: Если у Вас, grizzly, есть способ исправить то самое меню, донесите до нужного лица, что есть опечатка. Сообщал об этом не раз, но лицо на письмо не отозвалось ни ответом, ни действием.

Comment: @shampar Исправлено. У меня никакого блата нет :) Здесь на Мете есть тема про перевод сайта, где все в виде ответов на вопрос сообщают об обнаруженных опечатках. Реакция по этим сигналам очень оперативная.

Comment: @shampar ошибка исправлена. Спасибо! Скажите, пожалуйста, о каком письме идет речь? Обо всех недочетах лучше — и эффективнее — сообщать на Мете.

Comment: Через «Связаться с нами» писал. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте в текст ссылку https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315856/260198. Сюда репортить баги.

Comment: @Suvitruf Добавил. Спасибо.

Comment: @Aer, а с чем связан новый дизайн? Никак не могу привыкнуть. Цвет сайта очень бледный. Глаза болят.  Новые вопросы смешиваются со старыми. Путаница.

Comment: @Серж решение о редизайне приняла компания Stack Exchange, она хотела сделать универсальный внешний вид для всех сайтов, который, однако, можно будет как-то настраивать (менять цвета, например). Не знаю, можно ли это будет сделать для нас, но буду пытаться договориться. Если вы создадите отдельный вопрос здесь, на Мете, с пожеланиями к дизайну, будет замечательно!

Comment: @Aer Я когда-то давно походил по нескольким темам на разных SE, в которых обсуждался этот дизайн. Я не уверен, что понял правильно, но у меня сложилось такое впечатление, что унификация дизайна только первый шаг, а конечная цель — дать возможность каждому пользователю настроить индивидуальный дизайн, который можно будет одновременно применить ко всем форумам, в которых участвует этот пользователь. (Я не очень силён в английском и мог принять желаемое за действительное, но если всё так, тогда это хорошее решение.)

Comment: @Aer, мне нравился предыдущий дизайн.